# How to split up 123456789 into individual numbers using Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, split

How would you split up the number `123456789` into `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]` using Python?

Answer (score 10):

One way is to turn the number into a string first and then map each character digit back to an integer:

```
>>> map(int, str(123456789))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

This does the following:

- [`str`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#str) turns the integer into a string: `'123456789'`
- [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) applies the function [`int`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int) to each character in this string in turn, turning each one back into an integer value.
- a list of these integers is returned.

Comment: When using your method i get an error saying"TypeError: 'str' object in not callable"

Comment: Hmm... It sounds like you may have overwritten the builtin functions at some stage. Have you ever written assigned any of the functions to strings, e.g. `int = 'number'`?

Comment: @ajcr Seems more likely he might've reassigned `str`. phighter can check by printing it out: `print(str)` should give `<type 'str'>` and `print(int)` should give `<type 'int'>`.

Comment: @jpmc26 i tried that and i gave me <class 'int'> and <class 'str'> isthat normal

Comment: @phighter You must be using Python 3.x, even though your question is tagged with [tag:python-2.7]. And you did that in the same place where you're getting the error? That also has implications on this answer, since `map` seems to return a generator in Python 3.x

Comment: @jpmc26 thanks i figured out the problem all working

Comment: <map object at 0x0000021E0A3EAFD0>  in python 3.7.x

Answer (score 6):

You can convert the number into a string and then do a list comprehension -

```
>>>[int(digit) for digit in str(123456789)]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also do this without turning your number into a string like so:

```
def splitNum(n):
    if n < 10
        return [n]
    else:
        return splitNum(n // 10) + [n % 10]
```

This method uses recursion, but you can also do this without recursion

```
def splitNum(n):
    digits = []
    while n > 0:
        digits.insert(0, n % 10) # add ones digit to front of digits
        n = n // 10
    return digits
```

Both use the following facts:

- `x // 10`, because of integer division, "chops off" the ones digit, ie `1234 // 10` is `123`
- `x % 10` is that ones digit, ie `1234 % 10` is `4`

Comment: Note: this only works **without** `from __future__ import division`. If you have that enabled, you need to use the `//` operator for integer truncation.

Comment: Apologies. Forgot about Python 3.x, where it applies as well. Interestingly, from other comments, it looks like 3.x is exactly what the OP is using.

Answer (score 0):

Use the inbuilt `list` function in Python in the following way:

```
a = 123456789
p = str(a)
li = list(p)
s = []
for e in li:
    a = int(e)
    s.append(a)
print s
```

From the documentation:

```
list(iterable) -> new list initialized from iterable's items
```

EDIT:

Since the `list()` method returns a list containing only string elements, I have created an empty list `s`, and have then used a for loop to iterate through each string element, converted each of those elements to integer, and have then appended those elements inside the empty list `s`.

Comment: and what if OP wants a list of `int`?